# Obtaining a partial value from XPath

Tags: xpath

I have the current HTML code:

```
<div class="group">
    <ul class="smallList">
        <li><strong>Date</strong>
        13.06.2019
        </li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my "wrong" XPath:

```
//div[@class='group']/ul/li[1]
```

and I would like to extract the date with XPath without the text in the `strong` tag, but I'm not sure how NOT is used in XPath or could it even be used in here?

Keep in mind that the date is dynamic.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: //div[@class='group']/ul/li[0]/strong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substring-after()` to get the date value.

```
substring-after(//div[@class='group']/ul/li[1],'Date')
```

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the date is by using the XPath-1.0 expression

```
//div[@class='group']/ul/li[1]/text()[normalize-space(.)][1]
```

The result does include the spaces.
If you want to get rid of them, too, use the following expression:

```
normalize-space(//div[@class='group']/ul/li[1]/text()[normalize-space(.)][1])
```

Unfortunately this only works for one result in XPath-1.0.
If you'd have XPath-2.0 available, you could append the `normalize-space()` to the end of the expression which also enables the processing of multiple results:

```
//div[@class='group']/ul/li[1]/text()[normalize-space(.)][1]/normalize-space()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python method that will read the data directly from the parent in your case the data is associated with ul/li.

**Python:**

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    textValue += child.textContent;
                    child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

This is how to call this in your case.

```
  ulEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='group']/ul/li[1]")
  datePart = get_text_exclude_children(ulEle)
  print(datePart)
```

Please feel free to convert to the language that you are using, if it's not python.

Comment: its not programming! its rather xPath! XPath is used to navigate through elements and attributes in an html or XML documents!

Comment: Are you looking for the plain xpath solution? what ever you are using, does it support xpath 2.0? AFAIK you can not do it with xpath 1.0.